# Why can an Optional be initialized with a literal?

Tags: swift

Why does this work:

```
let xxx : Optional<Int> = 1
```

My expectation is that I would have to say the following (which also works):

```
let xxx : Optional<Int> = .Some(1)
```

Comment: Because syntactic sugar.  Everything about optionals is syntactic sugar.

Comment: And whatever is going on here isn't actually going to be different than assigning from a non-literal `Int`.  In your example, the literal is likely first converted to `Int`.  But that doesn't particularly change this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) book by Apple (emphasis is mine):

> The type Optional is an enumeration with two cases, None and
>   Some(Wrapped), which are used to represent values that may or may not
>   be present. Any type can be explicitly declared to be (**or implicitly
>   converted to**) an optional type. If you don’t provide an initial value
>   when you declare an optional variable or property, its value
>   automatically defaults to nil.

So, in Swift `Optional<Wrapped>` is just a special case of enum, for which implicit conversion from any type is defined, and the lines you wrote are actually equivalent. So [@nhgrif is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308399/why-can-an-optional-be-initialized-with-a-literal#comment60240387_36308399): it is a syntactic sugar.

**UPDATE** (from comments): since the assignment operator can not be overloaded, there really is no way to repeat this behaviour in your custom enum. It is a syntactic sugar in a way: it sort of "replaces" `1` with `.Some(1)` and `nil` with `.None`, but it is a "magical" syntactic sugar indeed.

Comment: Usually syntactic sugar can, alternately, be expressed directly. For instance, in the above expressions I am instantiating the optional directly instead of using the syntactic sugar "let xxx : Int? = 1" How can I write the literal assignment without the sugar? I am inclined to believe that what is going on is "magic". The compiler "knows" about the Optional enum and gives it special treatment. I tried to do something similar with my now enum but could not.

Comment: @RobertVaessen, since the assignment operator can not be overloaded, there really is no way to repeat this behaviour. It is a syntactic sugar in a way: it sort of "replaces" `1` with `.Some(1)` and `nil` with `.None`, but it is a "magical" syntactic sugar indeed.